# Why use a data-only container over a host mount?

Tags: linux, docker

I understand the concept of data-only containers

But why would you use a data-only container over a simple host mount given that data-only containers seem to make it harder to find the data.

Answer (score 1):

When you don't want to manage the mount yourself and don't need to find the data frequently. Good example is database containers, where using data-only container provides you with the following conveniences:

No need to even know what are the volumes that you have to create for a mature container, e.g.

```
docker run --name my-data tutum/mysql:5.5 true
docker run -d --name my --volumes-from my-data tutum/mysql:5.5
```

Simplified management via docker. You don't have to manually delete the host directory or create a new path when you need to start anew.

Comment: " You don't have to manually delete the host directory or create a new path when you need to start anew" Be aware though, if a container uses a volume, docker won't remove the volume when doing `docker rm <container>`. To also remove/cleanup the volume, use the `-v` option when deleting the container, so `docker rm -v <container>`. Otherwise you'll end up with "orphaned" volumes, that are hard to find (and get rid of)

Comment: You also don't have to worry about users/permissions on the host

Comment: @thaJeztah good point, although there seem to be automated ways: https://github.com/chadoe/docker-cleanup-volumes

Comment: @MykolaGurov yes. I can also highly recommend https://github.com/cpuguy83/docker-volumes, which is created by one of the Docker maintainers and offers a lot of functionality that may (eventually) become part of Docker itself, but hasn't been decided on yet.